# Why are the indices of the result of the tensor product of two different tensors just the sum of the upper and lower indices respectively?

Tags: tensor-products

Given two tensors $
T_{s}^{r} = 
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}}_{r}
\otimes
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}^{*}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}^{*}}_{s}
$ and $
T_{q}^{p} = 
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}}_{p}
\otimes
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}^{*}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}^{*}}_{q}
$

I think $
T_{s}^{r} \otimes T_{q}^{p} = \underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}}_{r}
\otimes
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}^{*}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}^{*}}_{s}
~\otimes~
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}}_{p}
\otimes
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}^{*}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}^{*}}_{q}
$
and $
T_{s+q}^{r+p} = 
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}}_{r+p}
\otimes
\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}^{*}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}^{*}}_{s+q}
$

I know that the tensor product is not commutative. So I think we can't move $\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}}_{p}$ to the front of $\underbrace{\boldsymbol{v}^{*}\otimes\cdots\otimes\boldsymbol{v}^{*}}_{s}$. If that, $T_{s}^{r} \otimes T_{q}^{p} \neq T_{s+q}^{r+p}$. However, the other definition is that $T_{s}^{r} \otimes T_{q}^{p} = T_{s+q}^{r+p}$

Are these two definitions contradictory?

Answer (score 1):

Your indices are playing different roles. One role is that it’s telling you the tensor type (e.g. $T^0_0$ is a function, $T^1_0$ is a vector field, and so on). This notation isn’t popular in DG; if anything people just explicitly say take an (p,q) tensor, or for (0,q) tensors people say consider $T\in\Omega^q(M)$.

The more common way to use indices is the second kind, namely to use them to index coordinate functions. Namely if you choose local coordinates $x^i$, this gives a local basis on the tangent space as $\partial_i$, which then induces a local dual basis $dx^i$ on the cotangent space. These bases naturally extend to a local basis for the space of (p,q) tensors by appropriately tensoring the bases. Since we have a basis, we must also have local coefficient functions, and this is what people use the indices for. For example if we take a vector field $X$, then locally we may write $X=X^i\partial_i$, where I’m using Einstein convention.